# Switching between two storyboards locks views

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, uistoryboard

First question here!
I have two storyboards in an app, a login and a main. After creating an account, the user proceeds to the MainStoryboard and all is well. But there are instances where the user may end up back in the LoginStoryboard to edit thier account info or just to log out, and then back to the MainStoryboard if need be.

Only in iOS 6 (in iOS 7, I have not been able to reproduce), the LoginStoryboard will sometimes lock up or quit responding to user interaction, but UIButtons usually work. Sometimes animations and the frames of subviews do not look right.

Repro:

```
LoginStoryboard > //login
MainStoryboard > //view content
LoginStoryboard > //update user info, for example
MainStoryboard > //back to content
LoginStoryboard > //back to user info
```

The last step is where things go wrong and the user is stuck in the LoginStoryboard as nothing will respond to interactions.

Here is an example of the code I'm using to load a new storyboard...

```
    - (void)navigateToHomeScreen 
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LoginStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *initialViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
        initialViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentViewController:initialViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

If I set a breakpoint on one of the didReceiveMemoryWarning methods after navigating back and forth between the LoginStoryboard and then simulate a memory warning on the simulator after the subviews have quit responding to the user, the breakpoint is hit 2-3 times on different instances of the same view controller.

So I think that I am either making new instances of these view controllers when I should be reusing old ones or the old instances are never getting dealloc-ed.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: It is a very bad design to have a separate storyboard for your login view controller, all these view controllers/views should be in the MainStoryboard

Comment: The LoginStoryboard is more than just one/two views to login. It is considerably sized and I felt it was warranted enough to separate the app into two storyboards for the sake of simplicity. I've read examples of multiple storyboards in an app with a MainStoryboard and a SettingsStoryboard. I feel that this is a similar situation.  

I would like to avoid consolidating both into one as it is the last thing I would like to attempt at the moment, seeing as the amount of work that would take. Why is it bad design?